# What can you do if money is missing/stolen from a wallet?

Tags: cash, losses, theft

I have found out just now that my mother has lost a decent lump of money (in my terms, $55 to $70) and it couldn't have just randomly disappeared. I am kind of concerned as my mother is and kind of want to know what to do. I dont know if it fell out of her wallet, or someone stole it from her. We sadly didn't record the serial numbers so we have assumed that its gone for good.

I dont really know what to do and kind of stressed.

Comment: Even if you recorded the serial numbers, what could you do?

Comment: I mean i guess i could report them to the bank?

Comment: I just need a little bit of help because my mother is stressing out, and i have alot on my mind as is.

Comment: And expect the bank to look at the serial numbers of each bill of the given denomination(s) they receive? That doesn’t seem practical, does it? Your best bet is probably the police. A police report might allow an insurance claim.

Comment: Ok thank you, You have helped me greatly.

Comment: Unlike other things, money doesn’t have a legal identity. If I steal your car and sell it, you can demand it back from the buyer. If I steal your money, use it in a store, and you find “your” bank notes in the store, you can’t demand them back.

Comment: @JosephCasey, sadly it could be worse. One of the worst experiences of my life:  years ago at a cash machine in France, I withdrew four hundred euros.  I walked off with my card and forgot about the cash.  A couple minutes later I dashed back around the corner but of course it was gone.  (I pray that at least some needy person got it.)  This is probably the single worst thing that has ever happened to me in life.  I know this doesn't help you, but, you can be sure everyone is sympathizing with you!  Especially me!

Comment: Ok We just now found the money and I thank all of you guy's help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but there is really nothing much you can do; consider it gone and learn to be more careful.

The police *might* file a report, but it is doubtful if you don’t have clear info when and where it happened - what would you expect them to do? They can hardly question anyone that was within five miles over the last two weeks or so. Also, the amount is too small to be of relevance (maybe it *is* relevant for your Mom, but not for the general public and the police).
Overall, you can only waste many hours with police and insurance, to get nothing from it.